# Scipy Installation Issue In Python 3.6.3 64-Bit on Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, scikit-learn, anaconda, nose

I have just installed **scipy 0.19.1** from **anaconda 3**.

When I type `help("modules")` in Python command prompt it does not pop up there.

To add, I have already installed **NumPy** and I lack **SciPy** to satisfy all the necessary requirements for **scikit-learn**.

Comment: Did you try to import scipy? How did you install it?

Comment: Show your try, way of installing modules, error list output, and give some information about your OS. Read   [mcve]